# Center text in multicol

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

I use multicol in order to describe a picture by adding text on the left/right.
But when I use multicol, the text and the picture are not well centered, how can I solve this ?

My code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article} % Type d'écrit
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry} % Début package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    Le cas de fonction reciproques : 
     \begin{multicols}{2}
       La fonction reciproque de s, notee arcsin, est la fonction qui prend un nombre $x$ dans [-1, 1] et renvoie l'angle $\alpha$ tel que : $sin(\alpha)=x$

\columnbreak

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics{Image/sin.png}
    \captionof{figure}{$sin : x \hookrightarrow sin(x)$}
\end{center}    

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result :
[image]

Comment: I'd use two  `minipage` environments instead of `multicols`.

Comment: Also, I get a different alignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcpm4.png. The only change I made in comparison to your original MWE: I have added the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some different alignments using teo `minipage` environments instead of `multicols`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article} % Type d'écrit
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry} % Début package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % remove demo option in actual document.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % adds the valign option

\begin{document}
    Le cas de fonction reciproques : 

    \noindent
     \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
       La fonction reciproque de s, notee arcsin, est la fonction qui prend un nombre $x$ dans [-1, 1] et renvoie l'angle $\alpha$ tel que : $sin(\alpha)=x$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics{Image/.png}
    \captionof{figure}{$sin : x \hookrightarrow sin(x)$}
\end{minipage}


    Le cas de fonction reciproques : 

    \noindent
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
       La fonction reciproque de s, notee arcsin, est la fonction qui prend un nombre $x$ dans [-1, 1] et renvoie l'angle $\alpha$ tel que : $sin(\alpha)=x$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[valign=t]{Image/.png}
    \captionof{figure}{$sin : x \hookrightarrow sin(x)$}
\end{minipage}




\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: @Juju In that case please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on its left.